# X2GO with Ubuntu Mate/Xfce 16.04 fails to start

Tags: xfce, 16.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, x2go

X2GO with Ubuntu Mate 16.04 fails to start with the following error message in `~/.xsession-x2go-errors`

```
XSession-x2go: X session started for testuser at Fri Apr  26 22:30:23 EDT 2016
localuser:testuser being added to access control list
/etc/x2go/Xsession: 3: [: x: unexpected operator
mate-session[3684]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
mate-session[3684]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
aborting...
```

Answer (score 6):

To work around the problem set in `~/.profile` the system default value for `XDG_DATA_DIRS` and to `GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR`.

```
export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/usr/share/mate:/usr/share/mate:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop

export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/mate:/usr/share/mate:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

great idea! I had this issue too. If you want to have x2go with Mate working for all users enabled I would put this

```
export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/usr/share/mate:/usr/share/mate:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/mate:/usr/share/mate:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

into `/etc/profile` instead. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

same thing on xfce4 but I didn't have the same error message:
more a lot of error message as:

```
    (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'gtk-cancel' for stock: Unrecognized image file format

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'image-missing' for stock: L'icône « image-missing » n'est pas présente dans le thème elementary-xfce-dark

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'gtk-cancel' for stock: Unrecognized image file format

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'image-missing' for stock: L'icône « image-missing » n'est pas présente dans le thème elementary-xfce-dark

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28411): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
```

now its working by just adding the 2 lines from your post and change mate to xfce4

Comment: Can you share the them?

Comment: Fixes the icons, but still doesn't work. Many applications (eg Firefox) don't start.

Comment: Also, I think the correct settings for Xubuntu are: `export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/usr/share/gconf/schemas:/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas; 
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/`