# No applications in xfce menu x2go

Tags: 16.04, xfce, x2go

I'm running Xubuntu through x2go.  When I run the computer locally it works fine, but when I remotely x2go into it, there are no aplications in the xfce menu - it acts as though there are no applications installed everywhere.  Most of the icons also seem to be missing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution for me :-)

Look at the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/764289/543219

I have added the following code at the end of file "/etc/profile":

```
export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/usr/share/gconf/schemas:/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
```

No it works. All Icons and the application menu are visible in the x2go session.